# Index Error: list index out of range (Python)

Tags: python, indexing

I am a beginner programmer and im not sure what this means...

Index Error: list index out of range

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to access an element outside the range of the list. What code is causing this error?

Comment: Paste your code so we can help solve your problem

Answer (score 51):

Generally it means that you are providing an index for which a list element does not exist.

E.g, if your list was `[1, 3, 5, 7]`, and you asked for the element at index 10, you would be well out of bounds and receive an error, as only elements 0 through 3 exist.