# Getting an error: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

when running this portion of my code I get the above error, the csv file has 3 values per row, first a name, then id number, lastly a numerical score. I can not figure out why it is saying the list index is out of range.

when I change the code inside the for loop to just print row it prints it out as if it was a list with 3 values.

the csv file looks like this

sean,12,15

harry,132,12

ben,3322,11

etc,

I've looked through the file to see if any rows did not have 3 values in each one but that was not the case. Each line has exactly 3 values seperated by 2 commas.

```
 points=[]
 names = []
 ids = []
 quiztakers = 0 
 totalscore = 0 
 with open('scoreFilecsv','r+') as score:
     reader = csv.reader(score,delimiter=',')
     for row in score:

         point = row[2]
         totalscore += point
         quiztakers += 1
         name = row[0]
         ids1 = row[1]
         points.append(point)
         names.append(name)
         ids.append(ids1)
```

Comment: we also tried changing score to reader but the same issue arose in line 7

Comment: There is exactly one reason for getting this error, which is using an index that is beyond the beginning or end of the list or array or collection, which means that one of the lines in your file does not contain what you think it does. We can't see your file or step through your code for you, so you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index Error: list index out of range (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005707/index-error-list-index-out-of-range-python)

Comment: @KenWhite i checked our csv file and all lines have 3 values so row[2] should be a valid index each iteration.

Comment: You're mistaken. There is exactly one reason to get this error. Please read my previous comment again (and the duplicate I linked above).

Answer (score 0):

- Below code is what I tried and it works

  ```
  points=[]
  names = []
  ids = []
  quiztakers = 0 
  totalscore = 0
  i = 0
  score = ["sean",12,15, "harry",132,12]
  new_row = []
  for row in score:

      if i != 0 and i%3 == 0:
          point = new_row[2] 
          totalscore += point
          quiztakers += 1
          name = new_row[0]  
          ids1 = new_row[1]  
          points.append(point)
          names.append(name)
          ids.append(ids1)
          new_row = []
      new_row.append(row)
      i += 1
  else:
      point = new_row[2] 
      totalscore += point
      quiztakers += 1
      name = new_row[0]  
      ids1 = new_row[1]  
      points.append(point)
      names.append(name)
      ids.append(ids1)
      new_row = []

  print(names)
  print(points)
  print(ids)
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  ['sean', 'harry']
  [15, 12]
  [12, 132]
  ```
- Looking at your code I believe in the `row` list because the length of `row` list at some point will be **definitely** less then 2
- I think you wanted to be `reader` variable over there instead of `score` variable (I am assuming looking at your code, but I am not sure, since I do not know what your input is in EXCEL is it in same row or different rows?)

  ```
   points=[]
   names = []
   ids = []
   quiztakers = 0 
   totalscore = 0 
   with open('scoreFilecsv','r+') as score:

       reader = csv.reader(score,delimiter=',')
       for row in score: # (Changing this line) for row in reader

           point = row[2] # you may be getting error here
           totalscore += point
           quiztakers += 1
           name = row[0]  # you may be getting error here
           ids1 = row[1]  # you may be getting error here
           points.append(point)
           names.append(name)
           ids.append(ids1)
  ```
- But looking at your description of input in the question, this is what I would do

  ```
   points=[]
   names = []
   ids = []
   quiztakers = 0 
   totalscore = 0
   i = 0
   with open('scoreFilecsv','r+') as score:
       reader = csv.reader(score,delimiter=',')
       new_row = []
       for row in reader:

           if i != 0 and i%3 == 0:
               point = new_row[2] 
               totalscore += point
               quiztakers += 1
               name = new_row[0]  
               ids1 = new_row[1]  
               points.append(point)
               names.append(name)
               ids.append(ids1)
               new_row = []
           new_row.append(row)
           i += 1
      else:
          point = new_row[2] 
          totalscore += point
          quiztakers += 1
          name = new_row[0]  
          ids1 = new_row[1]  
          points.append(point)
          names.append(name)
          ids.append(ids1)
          new_row = []
  ```
- Since you updated your question and input: I will go with the below code

  ```
   points=[]
   names = []
   ids = []
   quiztakers = 0 
   totalscore = 0 
   with open('scoreFilecsv','r+') as score:

       reader = csv.reader(score,delimiter=',')
       for row in reader: # (Changing this line) for row in reader
           row = row.split(",")
           point = row[2] 
           totalscore += point
           quiztakers += 1
           name = row[0]  
           ids1 = row[1]  
           points.append(point)
           names.append(name)
           ids.append(ids1)
  ```

Comment: You are welcome @Archer15 ... Can you please mark this answer as correct and give upvote